# Inicialización de miembro estático en clase plantilla

Tags: c++, c++98

El tema es muy simple, pero no *acierto* con la síntaxis a usar: inicializar una variable estática dentro de una clase plantilla:

```
#include <ctime>

template< bool NATIVE > class DateTimeTypeTraits;

template< > class DateTimeTypeTraits< true > {
  typedef time_t native_type;
};

template< typename TRAITS = DateTimeTypeTraits< true > > class DateTimeType {
  static DateTimeType ( *now )( );
};

template< typename TRAITS > DateTimeType< TRAITS > DateTimeType< TRAITS >::now = 0;

static DateTimeType< > doNow( );

int main( ) {
  DateTimeType< >::now = doNow;

  DateTimeType< > dtt( DateTimeType< >::now( ) );

  return 0;
}

DateTimeType< > doNow( ) {
  return DateTimeType< >( );
}
```

Al compilarlo con `g++ -std=c++98 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic` (si, es C++98) muestra el error:

> error: conflicting declaration ‘DateTimeType DateTimeType::now’

¿ Alguna solución ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si no fuese plantilla la inicialización sería:

```
DateTimeType (*DateTypeType::now)() = 0;
```

Luego con plantillas quedaría:

```
template<typename TRAITS>
DateTimeType<TRAITS> (*DateTimeType<TRAITS>::now)() = 0;
```

Comment: ¡¡ Ni 5 minutos !! ¡¡ Y llevo mas de media hora dándole vueltas !!

Comment: @Trauma C++ es así de bonito cuando buceas a través de sus entrañas

Comment: Oye, lo de *bonito* ... eso es sarcarmo, ¿ verdad ? O_o

Comment: @Trauma depende de a quien le preguntes... con C++ no hay medias tintas... o lo amas o lo aborreces